# Correct way of comparing old record with new record in trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

Can you please look at below and tell me if my analysis is correct.

I'm thinking that we should not compare oldrecords and new records in that fashion as we do not know the order in which they will be in the list. we could be comparing
newrecord1 with oldrecord2. Is my assumption correct ?

```
TriggerMethod(Map<Id, SObject> newItems, Map<Id, SObject> oldItems) {
    List newRecsList = newItems.values();
    List oldRecsList = oldItems.values();
    
    // Approach 1:(Which I think is wrong)
    Integer i=0;
    for(newrec : newRecsList) {
        if (newrec.field1 == oldRecsList[i]) {
           //Do stuff
        }
        i++;
    }
    
    //Approach 2: (Which I think is correct)
    for(newrec : newRecsList) {
        oldrec = oldMap.get(newrec.Id);
        if (newrec.field1 == oldrec.field2) {
            //Do stuff    
        }
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A List is an ordered collection. As such, `Trigger.old[index]` will always match up with `Trigger.new[index]`. You do not need to worry that they will somehow be shuffled or out of order.

```
for(Integer i = 0, s = Trigger.size; i < s; i++) {
  sObject oldRecord = Trigger.old[i], newRecord = Trigger.new[i];
  // ...
}
```

Note that this only applies if you're using `Trigger.old` and `Trigger.new`. If you're using `Trigger.oldMap` and `Trigger.newMap`, you should definitely get the old (or new) records by Id:

```
for(sObject newRecord: Trigger.newMap.values()) {
  sObject oldRecord = Trigger.oldMap.get(newRecord.Id);
  // ...
}
```

There is no explicit guarantee that Map.values() will return the records in the same order between both collections.

In general, I'd recommend avoiding the use of the Map objects, since using the List objects is generally easier to keep track of.